# delete data from database

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to delete some data from a database. But it shows me the following error:

```
Unmatched right curly bracket at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/db.pl line 13, at end of line\r
Missing $ on loop variable at C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.22/cgi-bin/ova/db.pl line 28.\r
```

The code:

```
package DBM;
use DBI;
use POSIX 'fmod';

#variabel globale qe formon connection string
our $rConn = {
    database => 'people',
    user     => 'root',
    pass     => '',
    host     => '127.0.0.1' 
};

#variabel global qe percakton rdbms qe do te perdoret (ex.mysql,postgres etj)
our $rdbms = "mysql";

#variabel global qe percakton handle per te kryer lidhjen me Databazen
our $dbh   = undef;

sub connection {
    $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:$rdbms:".$rConn->{database}.":". $rConn->{host}, $rConn->{user}, $rConn->{pass});
    return ($dbh);
};


sub do_delete {
    my $rData = @_;
    my $rCondition = $rData->{condition};
    my $cWhere = " WHERE 1=1 ";
    my $i=0;
    foreach my ($key,$value)($rCondition){

        if (scalar($value)>1){
            $cWhere .= " AND ". $key;
            my $counter=0;
            foreach my $cValueArray ($value){
                if(fmod($counter,3)==0) {
                    $cWhere.=" ".$key." ".$cValueArray." ";
                }
                else {
                    $cWhere.= " ".$value. " ";
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $cWhere .= " AND ". $key."=". $value;
        }
    }

    my $queryDelete = "DELETE FROM $rData->{table} $cWhere";
    return ($queryDelete);
    my $dbh = connection;  
    $dbh->prepare($queryDelete) or die "Can't prepare $queryDelete: $dbh->errstr\n";
    return ($sqlDelete->execute);
}
1;
```

I cant see where is that problem .

Comment: Use proper placeholders also!

Comment: Please put line numbers exactly as the program(db.pl) you executed, if possible.

Comment: Also,It seems, this is package DBM.pm and not db.pl. Can we have code of db.pl?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first error, but

```
foreach my ($key, $value) ($rCondition) {
```

seems strange. There can only be one loop variable, not a pair.

Comment: @Suic: Then he/she should use `while (my ($key, value) = each %$rCondition) {`.